# Unable to switch to parent window. The code for two windows is in different method

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have something like this

```
HtmlAutomationHelper.clickElementByXpath("//a/img");
        SynchronizationHelper.pause(5000);
        for (final String windowHandle : getWebDriver().getWindowHandles()) {
            HtmlAutomationHelper.switchToWindow(windowHandle);
        }
```

The above code will click on button and willl switch to new window. After performing some operations i.e. adding users it will click on add button which will close the child window. Now I want to switch to parent window and perform further operations. But it is not performing.

I have written following code to switch to parent window. But doesn't seem to be working

```
HtmlAutomationHelper.clickElementByClassName("Button");

        SynchronizationHelper.pause(4000);
        //      final String old = getWebDriver().getWindowHandle();
        //      HtmlAutomationHelper.switchToWindow(old);

        for (final String s : getWebDriver().getWindowHandles())
            HtmlAutomationHelper.switchToWindow(s);
```

In this it will click on button and switch to parent window. Since I am clicking
     HtmlAutomationHelper.clickElementByClassName("Button");
the child window will be closed and subsequent code will switch to parent window

Please help with this

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this to switch to diff window handles and coming back to parent window

 String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
 for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
  {
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
  }
for (String handle1 : driver.getWindowHandles())
{ 
   driver.switchTo().window(handle1);
}
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);//switch to parent window
```